# concat while inserting new row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello i am trying to insert string concatenation based on prefix `'p'` and total number of rows.
result should be as `p1,p2,p3,p4....`

i tried executing following query

```
insert into products(pid) values(concat('p1',count(*)))

gives error: invalid use of group function

pid is varchar(5),
```

i also tried replacing `count(*)` with `select count(*) from products.`

i know i can do this programmatically in `php` by first retrieving number of rows and then inserting new row.

looking forward for correct sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try  below code:

```
insert into products(pid) select concat('p1',count(*))
```

**EDIT**

```
insert into products(pid) select concat('p1',count(*)) from products
```

Comment: hi your query does work but count(*) return 1 every time so i modified your query to
insert into products(pid) select concat('p',(1+(select count(*) from products)))
the above query does work
i tried surrounding select concat with values() but doesn't work coz i also need to insert values in other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use variables for this?

```
DECLARE @cnt INT;
SET @cnt = (SELECT count(*) FROM products);

insert into products(pid) values (concat('p',@cnt));
```

Also, not sure what are you trying to count, so I assumed it's your products table, which might not be the case.

**EDIT**

In PHP this would be something like

(please use proper methods for database queries and connections - such as PDO - , I'll use simple mysql for example)

```
<?php
     $qry = "SELECT count(*) FROM products";
     $qry = mysql_query($qry, $db);
          while($row = mysql_fetch_row($qry)) 
          {
              $secondqry = "INSERT INTO products(pid) VALUES ('p".echo $row[0]."'");
              $secondqry = mysql_query($secondqry);
          }
?>
```

Comment: hi alex, yes products is the table and pid is primary key with varchar(5) and there are other column also. i kept the primary key as varchar coz i wanted the product id to be p1,p2,p3.... and so on.
how am i suppose to execute above statement "declare and set" via PHP ?
i tried the following it worked for me but i dont know how to update other columns
insert into products(pid) select concat('p',(1+(select count(*) from products)))

Comment: ya i know i can do this way but i thought it would be more appropriate if a single sql query statement can do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this 
Try to concat like a simple string it works in sqlserver

```
insert into Products(PID) values select 'P'+convert(nvarchar(50),count(*)) from Products
```

this will do the job

Comment: Maybe you can try this by using char(50) instead of nvarchar(50)